# Refresh page and fetch latest image from folder

Tags: javascript, image, webcam

I have set up a basic webcam, and have it saving a new image to a folder on my web server once every minute.

I want to be able to access a webpage on the same folder in the webserver, which will refresh very (say) 30 seconds and display the most recent image.

Lets assume all images are in the following format:
"cam1-11-05-2018-13-46.jpg"
and none are deleted, the webcam just adds to the folder.

How can I achieve this? maybe a simple javascript can access a folder listing, order by date and fetch the most recent?

Thanks!

Comment: you will need a smart web server.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you are describing is not possible. As you describe, you need to read files within a folder in some way with JavaScript in client side, fortunately **this is not possible**.

The easiest way is just providing a name which you could guess from JavaScript, for example always the same name for the last image, or a name ending in a number incremental.